# How to copy only specific file types from local network to PC folder with CMD?

Tags: cmd.exe

I need to copy some specific from my local network to my computer. Thing is, I can't do it all individually, as the network contains easily over 50 GB of data, waaaay too much to manually sift through. So I need to move only specific file formats (.mp3, .wav, .mp4). How would I go about doing this? I am very new to this and have no idea what I'm doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Give me all the file types you want to copy, the network path, the local path, whether it should look for this file types in all network subfolders?

Comment: You can use the solution to this old question to get the job done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one

Comment: @mrwhale he should with echo first,  and count the number of copies, and make sure it's the same. and check that it's fine for files with spaces too

Comment: @mrwhale that only mentions doing it for one extension. This kind of command would list for multiple extensions `for /r %f in (*.txt *.docx) do @echo %f`

Comment: also if you use a copy command like that that link, so it goes through all  subdirectories from some root directory, and it finds each file and copies them into one destination directory, not into separate subdirectories, then one has to consider that it won't work so well if there are two identical filenames. Also if it matters what subdirectory a file is in then you won't have that either.

Comment: @barlop yeah that's why I just added that link as a comment, not an answer. Good stepping stone to make the script into something useful for this specific case. OP could just run the script multiple times, changing the extension if they couldn't figure out how to extend the script to use multiple extensions

Comment: read this [xcopy directories and subdirectories recursively and filter only filenames by extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952337/xcopy-directories-and-subdirectories-recursively-and-filter-only-filenames-by-ex)

Answer (score 1):

you need only two commands

1. use `net use` to connect a shared resource
2. use `xcopy` to copy files

example script:

```
net use z: \\some_host\$c secret_password /user:some_domain\some_user
md g:\xc
xcopy z:*.mp3 g:\xc\ /E /C /I /G /H /Z /B
xcopy z:*.wav g:\xc\ /E /C /I /G /H /Z /B
xcopy z:*.mp4 g:\xc\ /E /C /I /G /H /Z /B
```

where `net use` parameters are:

```
z:               - some free drive letter
\\some_host\$c   - default windows C:\ share on some_host in your network
/user:           - user that have access to this share
secret_password  - this user password
```

where `xcopy` parameters are:

```
z:*.mp3      Source and file mask
g:\xc\       Destination
/E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
/C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
/I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
             assumes that destination must be a directory.
/G           Allows the copying of encrypted files to destination that does
             not support encryption.
/H           Copies hidden and system files also.
/Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
/B           Copies the Symbolic Link itself versus the target of the link.
```

you can do copy in reverse way in all current domain computers using psexec if you specify a wildcard (`\\*`) as computer

```
psexec \\* -u some_domain\some_user -p secret_password -h -c script.cmd
```

where

```
 -u         Specifies optional user name for login to remote
            computer.
 -p         Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
            you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
 -h         If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
            run with the account's elevated token, if available.
 -c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
            execution. If you omit this option the application
            must be in the system path on the remote system.
```

example `script.cmd`:

```
net use z: \\your_host\some_share
xcopy c:*.mp3 z:\ /E /C /I /G /H /Z /B /R /Y
net use z: /delete
```

where you should use additional parameters:

```
/R           Overwrites read-only files.
/Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
             existing destination file.
```

Comment: And all you need to build a house is lumber and nails. Some instructions on how to use them would be useful.

Comment: If you're using Windows Vista or above, Robocopy is generally better than xcopy.

Comment: this is an alternative, so write your own answer, for copy few type files he can use `xcopy` - it is simple.